# Как определить, принадлежит ли ip к выходным нодам сети TOR или I2P?

Tags: tor

Даже не знаю, возможно ли конкретизировать данный вопрос. Существует ли механизм определения, пришел ли пользователь на твой сайт из TOR или I2P?

Для тех, кто не в курсе, что за звери эти пользователи TOR и I2P, ниже дана краткая справка.

> Tor (сокр. от англ. The Onion Router) — свободное и открытое программное обеспечение для реализации второго поколения так называемой луковой маршрутизации. Это система прокси-серверов, позволяющая устанавливать анонимное сетевое соединение, защищённое от прослушивания. Рассматривается как анонимная сеть виртуальных туннелей, предоставляющая передачу данных в зашифрованном виде. С помощью Tor пользователи могут сохранять анонимность в Интернете при посещении сайтов, ведении блогов, отправке мгновенных и почтовых сообщений, а также при работе с другими приложениями, использующими протокол TCP.

Информация со [страницы TOR википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor).

> I2P (аббревиатура от англ. invisible internet project, IIP, I2P — проект «Невидимый интернет») — анонимная компьютерная сеть.
>
> Сеть I2P является оверлейной, устойчивой (отключение узла не повлияет на функционирование сети), анонимной (невозможно или сложно определить IP-адрес узла) и децентрализованной (не имеющей центрального сервера). При передаче данных между узлами сети применяется шифрование.
> Сеть предоставляет приложениям транспортный механизм для анонимной и защищённой пересылки сообщений друг другу. Кроме того, существуют шлюзы для доступа в сеть I2P непосредственно из Интернета, созданные специально для пользователей, которые по разным причинам не могут установить на компьютер программное обеспечение проекта "Невидимый Интернет".

Информация со [страницы I2P википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2P).

Comment: Тор определить можно. С i2p сложнее. Прочитайте про  i2p на официальном сайте i2p.